# How to load static files in an Nginx + Flask setup if the app is mapped to a sub-directory

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a basic html site running at a domain (say example.com) and I want to run a flask app in a sub-directory (eg:example.com/test)
flask app is running on port 5433 using the default flask development server.

I used the following nginx configuration to achieve this

```
location /test {
           rewrite /test(.*) $1 break;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:5433;
           proxy_redirect     default;
           proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static/{
    alias /home/hrishi/www/example.com/test/app/static/;
    }
```

I am able to access the app using the example.com/test/ url but the static files fails to load(gives 404 error) despite the alias.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not a subdomain. I subdomain start before your domain name. In your case, it will be test.exemple.com. In this case, it will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because there an extra

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
expires           max;
```

}

inside the server block, I removed it and changed the permission of static directory by

```
chmod -R 664 /the/path/to/static/dir
chmod a+X /the/path/to/static/dir
```

and it worked like a charm